Sort Map using java streams
How to sort a map with the key first and sort the values as well.
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("Apple", Arrays.asList("iphone", "imac"));
myMap.put("Samsung", Arrays.asList("galaxys", "galaxyz"));
myMap.put("LG", Arrays.asList("ultra", "tab"));

//sort logic
Sort with the key first {Apple, LG, Samsung} and then sort the values based on the key.

Result:
imac, iphone, tab, ultra, galaxys, galaxyz


so basically you want each list being sorted independently (first), and then sorting by key and all lists (values) concatenated

Correct. Sort the key first and based on the sorted key sort the values list (concatenated).

If you want the map sorted by key why not use a TreeMap?

First, stream on the entries of the map. Hence, sort them using the Map.Entry.comparingByKey() comparator. Now that you have a list of entries sorted by keys, map the values (lists) by sorting them through Collections.sort(). Hence, flatmap and collect to list.

You have a critical problem: HashMap is unordered, and so sorting it doesn't actually make sense. There's LinkedHashMap for insertion order, or TreeMap extends SortedMap for... a sorted map.

It's easier to work out stream problems by making a plan. An example one for this problem would be:

Get a stream from the map using Key, Value pairs (Stream<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>>)
Sort by the keys
Get the value (lists) from the sorted keys; to get a stream of lists in the correct order (Stream<List<String>>)
Sort the lists
Combine the elements of every list into one stream (Stream<String>)
Collect the stream into the final list (List<String>)


You'd first have to convert the map to an entrySet to allow you to stream over the Map.Entry entries. Then we can get the lists sorted via the map key with .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()) and .map(Map.Entry::getValue).
Once we have the lists in sorted order, the elements within are not sorted. So we then need to flatten them (go from a Stream<List<String>> to Stream<String> containing the elements of the lists) in sorted order: .flatMap(list -> list.stream().sorted())
Resulting in the code:
List<String> result = myMap.entrySet().stream() // Step 1
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())         // Step 2
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)                   // Step 3
    .flatMap(list -> list.stream().sorted())    // Step 4+5
    .collect(Collectors.toList());              // Step 6

You can also skip the mapping from Map.Entry::getValue, doing .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().sorted()) directly, but it's a bit less clear what's going on.

Or 4+5 can use method references .map(List::stream).flatMap(Stream::sorted)

Or go into the other direction and fuse step 3 to 5 into one, .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().sorted())

According to Brian Goetz method references are no better than lambdas.  Use which ever makes more sense to you.

Note that HashMap is unordered: there is no notion of sorting a HashMap at all. When you modify the map, the order of the keys can change unpredictably. For this case, we can use a TreeMap (which extends SortedMap), to avoid the ordering problem of HashMap:
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new TreeMap<>();
myMap.put("Apple", Arrays.asList("iphone", "imac"));
myMap.put("Samsung", Arrays.asList("galaxys", "galaxyz"));
myMap.put("LG", Arrays.asList("ultra", "tab"));

This allows you to get a sorted output directly with streams (note the #sort call inside of #flatMap):
List<String> sorted = myMap.values().stream().flatMap(l -> l.sort().stream()).toList();
// ["imac", "iphone", "tab", "ultra", "galaxys", "galaxyz"]

A better approach may be keeping the internal lists (read: sets) sorted to begin with:
Map<String, Set<String>> myMap = new TreeMap<>();
myMap.put("Apple", new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList("iphone", "imac")));
myMap.put("Samsung", new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList("galaxys", "galaxyz")));
myMap.put("LG", new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList("ultra", "tab")));

Now your values will always be sorted, even when updated:
myMap.get("Apple").add("ipad");
List<String> sorted = myMap.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).toList();
// ["imac", "ipad", "iphone", "tab", "ultra", "galaxys", "galaxyz"]


Note that this solution is preferable if you can control the type of the Map, but not if you're just given a Map<X,Y> and have to sort it in this way. Though the question doesn't mention if this is or isn't the case.

If that's the case, they can take a look at your answer :). Note Java 16 introduced Stream#toList, for convenience of typing.

@ipodtouch0218 is right, the Map is given and I dont have the control over it. So the given Map is unfortunately a HashMap.

Here is a sort of hybrid solution.

create an ArrayList<String>
sort the Entry values in place.
then sort the map by keys and iteratively add the presorted lists to the result list.

 List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
 myMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> e.getValue().sort(null));
 myMap.entrySet().stream()
         .sorted(Entry.comparingByKey())
         .map(Entry::getValue)
         .forEach(lst -> result.addAll(lst));

prints
[imac, iphone, tab, ultra, galaxys, galaxyz]  


Instead of myMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> e.getValue().sort(null)); you can use myMap.values().forEach(v -> v.sort(null));, myMap.values().forEach(Collections::sort);, or myMap.forEach((k, v) -> v.sort(null)); But keep in mind that this assumes that the lists in the original map are mutable.

@Holger Simply hadn't considered using values directly. But I did consider the mutability of the lists.  Based on the OP's supplied data and construct I figured it was OK.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Yes, in the question’s example code, the mutability is given. But it may be an oversimplified example, so it’s worth mentioning the constraints explicitly.


public static  Map<String, List<String>> sortMapList(Map<String, List<String>> myMap) {
        Map<String, List<String>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>();
        myMap.entrySet().stream()
            .forEach(x -> sortedMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue().stream()
            .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()))
            );
        return sortedMap;
    }



This returns a map, not a flat list. Plus, the fact that you initialize sortedMap as HashMap gives you no guarantees that the keys will still be sorted when you loop on it. also, there is a way to create the list directly through collect without the need of an intermediate object

Map.Entry.comparingByKey() compares Map.Entry in natural order on key.

You iterate over the map in order, but you're putting it back into an unordered HashMap, which only results in the Lists being sorted. The sort via key is effectively ignored.

Instead of myMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(x -> …), calling x.getKey() and x.getValue() in the function, you can use myMap.forEach((key, value) -> …) in the first place.
